# Is it impossible to stream video using local HTTP server to another player app?

Tags: ios, http, background-process

Many file browser apps on Android open remote video files in the following procedure. Let us call the file browser app A, and a third-party video app B.

1. A starts downloading the video file from a remote location.
2. A starts a local HTTP server and make the video available on that server.
3. A opens B passing the HTTP video address to B.

In short, is this possible in iOS? I am new to iOS development, and I have quickly browsed the iOS documentation, and it seemed this kind of background processing was not listed.

A and B are different apps, but logically A is using B as a part of A, as if the mail app could use the photo app to let users select a photo to insert to a mail. So, to me, if A has opened B delegating part of its task, one may still regard A as the foreground app while B is running in the foreground. But this is just my wishful thinking, and I would like to know if it is possible.